# Datatables "print" button not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Whenever I add dom and buttons, my search and "show x entries" disappears, breaking the datatable. I cannot seem to figure out what I am missing to get the print button to show.

Debug: http://debug.datatables.net/ireroh

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'print'
            ]
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "columnDefs": [
                { "searchable": false, "targets": [0, 1] }
            ]
    });
});

<script src="../bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add database button js file..

> https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
>   //cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js
>
> https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css

for more info check below.

```
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html
```

Comment: Check my question, I have them already loaded. Could it be incorrect?

Comment: the order isn't correct. Can you change the order of `buttons.print.min.js` and `dataTables.buttons.min.js`. also check this which I cloned from your link. http://live.datatables.net/vukoxagu/1

Answer (score 1):

You must write like this, first load script files;

```
    <script src="../bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'print'
            ]
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "columnDefs": [
                { "searchable": false, "targets": [0, 1] }
            ]
    });
});
```